# Java user input is a array type in switch case

Tags: java

I'm just starting to learn Java. I want my input (an array) to accept an x and y value, for example `RR ,S`.

The result comes out but the problem is if I input the value `R,R` the output returns `default`, not the matching `case`. I think I did something wrong with the scanner - I think it's not `a.next()` but I don't know what to put there...

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class testa {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner a = new Scanner (System.in);

        String Rotate;
        String[] Position = new String[]{"R", "S", "RR", "E", "RS"};

        System.out.println("Rotate Equation?");
        Rotate = a.next();

        String[] values = new String[5];

        values[0] = "R";
        values[1] = "S";
        values[2] = "RR";
        values[3] = "RS";
        values[4] = "RRS";

        switch (Arrays.toString(values))
        {
        //cases with "RR" resulted
        case "[R, R]":
        case "[S, RS]":
        case "[RRS,S]":
            System.out.println("RR");
            break;
            //cases with "E" resulted
        case "[R,RR]":
        case "[RR,R]":
        case "[S,S]":   
        case "[RS,RS]":
        case "[RRS,RRS]":
            System.out.println("E");
            break;
            //cases with "RS" resulted
        case "[R,S]":
        case "[RR,RRS]":
        case "[S,RR]":  
        case "[RRS,R]":
            System.out.println("RS");
            break;
            //cases with "RRS" resulted
        case "[R,RS]":
        case "[RR,S]":
        case "[S,R]":   
        case "[RS,RR]":
            System.out.println("RRS");
            break;
            //cases with "S" resulted
        case "[R,RRS]":
        case "[RR,RS]":
        case "[RS,R]":  
        case "[RRS,RR]":
            System.out.println("S");
            break;
            //cases with "R" resulted
        case "[RR,RR]":
        case "[S,RRS]":
        case "[RS,S]":
        case "[RRS,RS]":
            System.out.println("R");
            break;
        case "x:D3":
            System.out.println("x");
            break;
            //other input will be invalid
        default :
            System.out.println("Invalid move");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At no point in your code do you reference rotate as a value. Really not much about your code makes too much sense.

Comment: I fully agree. What do all the abbreviations stand for?

Answer (score 0):

For this array:

```
String[] values = new String[5];

values[0] = "R";
values[1] = "S";
values[2] = "RR";
values[3] = "RS";
values[4] = "RRS";
```

The return of:

```
Arrays.toString(values)
```

Will be:

```
[R, S, RR, RS, RRS]
```

Which doesn't match any of your case statements.

As it stands now, with you creating case statements based on the result of an `Arrays.toString()` is a really bad way of doing things.

1. It's highly unreadable and inefficient.
2. It's not maintainable because you are dependent on the `Arrays.toString()` implementation.

**Note**: I don't fully understand what you are trying to do, so please take the below example as just another way of approaching your problem and not as the replacement to your code:

With that said, a better approach could be to loop through your array and have conditions in the for loop that satisfy your criteria.

Example:

```
boolean validMove = false;
for (String s : values)
{
   if (s.indexOf("RS") != -1)
   {
       System.out.println("RS");
       validMove = true;
       break;
   }
   else if (s.indexOf("RR") != -1)
   {
       System.out.println("RR");
       validMove = true;
       break;
   }
   // the rest of your else if's ...
}

// this would be your default check
if (!validMove)
{
    System.out.println("Invalid move");
}
```

**EDIT**:

Another approach would be to use Regular Expressions.

Comment: oh I'm sorry that my code does not make sense. I'm new after all. But what i mean to do is my input accept [x,y] value which is those "R ,RS , etc" and those case that's you guys said doesn't match i tried to write that if i input [RR,RR] output is R as well as the other so in your if else function i can add value check in if statement right?

Comment: Correct. You can include many in one if condition. For example, `if ( s.indexOf("R") != -1 || s.indexOf("S") != -1)`

Comment: s.indexOf("R") != -1  i don't understand what this code do.  does it mean s have "R" and not equal to -1?? my little brain exploded. well being said i want to check that the input is [R,R]  then in if condition i should write {if (s.contains("R,R")} ????